# Solving 2D Poisson Equation with one inhomogeneous Dirichlet Boundary Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I'm familiar how to go about solving problems with separation of variables, but I'm very confused on how to get started with a problem that has inhomogeneous boundary conditions. For example:

[image]

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This problem is actually quite simple. You can tackle one homogeneity at a time (in the equation and on the boundary).

First, separate the solution into $u(x,y) = v(x,y) + u_p(x,y)$, where one is a particular solution is and the other is a homogeneous solution. For the particular solution, notice the RHS function has derivatives that are proportional to itself, so you can guess a solution of the form $$ u_p(x,y) = A\sin (x) \sin (2y) $$

Plugging this into the equation, you will obtain $A = \dfrac15$

For the homogeneous solution, you first have to subtract off the boundary from the particular solution. Lucky for you, $u_p(x,y)$ is zero everywhere on the boundary, so everything remains the same. The problem is reduced to

$$ v_{xx} + v_{yy} = 0 $$
$$ v(0,y) = v(\pi,y) = v(x,0) = 0, \ v(x,\pi)=\sin x  $$

Let $v(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$, then separation of variables gives
\begin{cases} X'' + \lambda X = 0, & X(0) = X(\pi) = 0 \\
Y'' - \lambda Y = 0, & Y(0) = 0 \end{cases}

Solving these we get

$$ v(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\sin(nx) \sinh(ny) $$

Note that the inhomogeneous B.C is not a disadvantage here. You *need* it to find the remaining constants

$$ v(x,\pi) = \sin x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\sinh(n\pi) \sin(nx) $$

This implies
\begin{cases} c_n\sinh(n\pi) = 1, & n = 1 \\ c_n\sinh(n\pi) = 0, & n \ne 1 \end{cases}

So the final solution is

$$ u(x,y) = \frac15 \sin (x) \sin (2y) + \frac{\sin (x)\sinh (y)}{\sinh (\pi)} $$